# SUBSTRING Empty Value Alternatives

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query which works and does what is supposed to do:

```
select 
SUBSTRING(LastName,2,1)
+SUBSTRING(LastName,3,1)
+SUBSTRING(LastName,5,1) 
+SUBSTRING(FirstName,2,1) 
+SUBSTRING(FirstName,3,1)
+replace(convert(varchar, DateOfBirth,101),'/','')
+CASE WHEN GenderID = '1' Then '1' WHEN GenderID = '2' Then '2' ELSE '9' END
from 
    Client
```

However if any of the SUBSTRINGS return an empty string, it needs to be replaced with 2. For example if LastName is Bond, SUBSTRING(LastName,5,1) needs to return a 2.

How would anyone suggest this is done? I was trying to avoid something like this:

```
select CASE WHEN SUBSTRING('James',5,1) = '' THEN '2' ELSE SUBSTRING('James',5,1) END
```

Comment: You don't want to use CASE, because it doesn't look nice, but it's mainly *cut&paste&modify*, easier to understand than LEFT or ISNULL/NULLIF and not less performant than those :-)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the simplest method:

```
select (SUBSTRING(LastName + '22222', 2, 1) +
        SUBSTRING(LastName + '22222', 3, 1) +
        SUBSTRING(LastName + '22222', 5, 1)  +
        SUBSTRING(FirstName + '22222', 2, 1) +
        SUBSTRING(FirstName + '22222', 3, 1) +
        replace(convert(varchar(255), DateOfBirth, 101), '/', '') +
        (CASE WHEN GenderID IN ('1', '2') THEN GenderID ELSE '9' END)
       )
from Client;
```

This just adds enough `'2'`s to the end to be sure that the `substring()` finds a character.

Note two other changes.  I added a length parameter to `varchar()`.  You should always use a length parameter, because the default length varies by context -- leading to hard-to-find errors.  I also simplified the logic for `GenderId` (it assumes that `GenderId` is a string).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one trick:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(SUBSTRING(LastName, 2, 1) + '2', 1) AS first_part
FROM Client
```

Should the call to `SUBSTRING` return an empty string output, then the call to `LEFT` would return `'2'`.  Otherwise, `LEFT('#2', 1)` would return the number from the call to `SUBSTRING` (here I use `#` to represent any number).

As @dnoeth pointed out in his comment, this solution would only work if the substring length is 1, which appears to be the case for your query/data.

Comment: This only works for a length of `1`, otherwise you might get a wrong result, e.g. select `LEFT(SUBSTRING('foo', 3, 2) + '2', 2)`

Comment: @dnoeth I assume that the substring call will always cover actual in-bounds text.  Yes, as you pointed out, my answer would fail if this be not the case.  I will add a disclaimer to my answer.

Comment: If the substring always covers actual in-bound text there would be no need for replacing an empty string :-) Of course your solution is nice for the single character returned by the orignal select.

Comment: @dnoeth I've been chewing on your comment for the last 5 minutes, and I see what you mean now.  I'll leave this up with the caveats you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**: If you wish to use `IIF` for `SQL SERVER 2012 or +`

```
SELECT IIF (SUBSTRING('James',6,1)='', '2', SUBSTRING('James',5,1))
```